# Create automated reports from Google Analytics from multiple GA views

Tags: google-analytics, google-sheets-api, looker-studio

Does anyone know if you can created automated reports from multiple GA views? I have a different views in GA setup for different localised webpages.

For example: I want to create a report of bounce rates that is automated for multiple views - then show this report in a dashboard - maybe through Google Data Studio or Google Sheets?

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Mucho Appreciato

Comment: Could you elaborate by providing a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report (additionally, a Google Sheet if it's the data set) of the scenario (using sample data that shows 1) Input values (~10 rows) 2) Expected output 3) An attempt at solving the issue)? It would help users visualise the issue and test out suggestions on a specific use case with objective right / wrong answers. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to pinpoint a suggestion and the issue, e.g. Data Set, Data Source, Report, Fields, Chart.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely use the [Google Analytics spreadsheet addon](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on) for that, this will allow you to:

1. copy really easily the same report configuration for all view
2. aggregate data from each of these views in the separate spreadsheet

Depending on what you want to show in your dashboard, an efficient visualisation in Data Studio might be impossible, as you will not be able to mix data sources (your different views) in the same graphical element, table or scorecard.